# Returning textfield after buttonclick

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

I'm trying to move a string from one screen to another.

Once the program is started I create a screen with a button.

Clicking this button I create a new screen with a textField and a button.

I want the program to return what the user writes in the textfield after they click the second button.

I tried to put it inside the second buttons lambda, but that did not work

```
( e -> {
            String name= ConfirmBox.register();
            return name;
        });
```

The second thing I noticed was that in my first buttons actionListener

```
button.setOnAction(e -> {
        String string= ConfirmBox.register();
        System.out.print(string);   
    });
```

I get the output null once i press the first button. Im guessing this is because the return is to quick, but how do I slow it down so that I get the correct return after the user have pressed the button?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("titel");
        button = new Button("button");
        
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            String string= ConfirmBox.register();
            System.out.print(string);   
        });
     }


 public class ConfirmBox {
     static String save; 

public static String register() {

    Stage window = new Stage();
    
    window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    window.setTitle("title");
    
    Label label = new Label("enter tekst");
    TextField tekstField = new TextField();
    Button button = new Button("ok");
    
    
    
    button.setOnAction(e-> 
    {
        /*
        String name= ConfirmBox.register();
        return name;
        */

    save  = tekstField.getText();
    window.close();
    });

    GridPane layout = new GridPane();
    GridPane.setConstraints(label, 0, 0);
    GridPane.setConstraints(tekstField, 0, 1);
    GridPane.setConstraints(button, 0, 2);
        
    layout.getChildren().addAll(label, tekstField, button);
    Scene scene = new Scene (layout, 300, 250);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();

    return save;
        
    }   
}
```

Comment: You tagged the question with JFrame, which belongs to Swing, but your cvode looks like you are using JavaFX.

Comment: correct. I changed it now

Comment: I think if you just change `window.show()` to `window.showAndWait()` this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the `return` statement is executed essentially immediately, so before the user has pressed the button, causing the `String save` to be set.

Instead of `window.show()`, use [`window.showAndWait()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#showAndWait()), which will block execution until the window is closed, achieving the desired result. Note that there's no real reason to have a variable for this at this point, you can just look up the value in the text field:

```
public class ConfirmBox {

    public static String register() {
    
        Stage window = new Stage();
        
        window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        window.setTitle("title");
        
        Label label = new Label("enter tekst");
        TextField tekstField = new TextField();
        Button button = new Button("ok");
        
        
        
        button.setOnAction(e -> window.close());
    
        GridPane layout = new GridPane();
        GridPane.setConstraints(label, 0, 0);
        GridPane.setConstraints(tekstField, 0, 1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(button, 0, 2);
            
        layout.getChildren().addAll(label, tekstField, button);
        Scene scene = new Scene (layout, 300, 250);
        window.setScene(scene);
        
        //window.show();
 
        window.showAndWait();
    
        return tekstField.getText();
        
    }   
}
```

It's worth remarking here that you're reinventing the wheel to some degree. Have a look at the [`TextInputDialog` class](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextInputDialog.html), and related classes such as `Dialog` and `Alert`.